# What am I doing wrong? Trying to make a table (rows = sales per quarter, columns = salesperson)

Tags: delphi, pascal

In this program, you enter three pieces of info relating to each sale: salesnumber from salesperson, sales quarter, and amount of sale. If you have more than one sale for the same salesperson, my program makes an extra column instead of adding the amount of the sale to an already existing column for that salesperson (Sorry, I am a noob at explaining this and at learning how to program, so if I am not explaining something very well, please let me know.) In the end, I want to produce a table with just one column for each sales person, not each sale (which is what I seem to have now).

For instance, with the following input:

- sNr: 100, q: 1, amt: 50
- sNr: 200; q: 2, amt: 50
- sNr: 300, q: 3, amt: 50
- sNr: 100, q: 1, amt: 25

I would want to see three columns, one for each salesperson's number (100, 200, 300), and combined sales for each quarter under each salesperson's number (first quarter being the row under the salesperson's numbers, second quarter under that, etc.). For quarters with  no sales a 0 shows up.

At this moment, I get a separate row for each of the four (or more) entries, even if there are more than one entry per salesperson.

Here is what shows up when I run the program.

```
Input sales number from sales person.
100
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
1
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
200
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
2
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
300
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
3
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
100
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
1
Give amount of sale.
25
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
0
  100  200  300  100
   50    0    0   25
    0   50    0    0
    0    0   50    0
    0    0    0    0

Press < ENTER > to stop the program.
```

I would like this output:

```
Input sales number from sales person.
100
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
1
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
200
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
2
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
300
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
3
Give amount of sale.
50
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
100
Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .
1
Give amount of sale.
25
Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.
0
  100  200  300
   75    0    0
    0   50    0
    0    0   50
    0    0    0

Press < ENTER > to stop the program.
```

Below is my code. Can someone help me?

```
program Sales;

var arrayN: array of integer;
var arrayS: array of array of integer;
var max, row, column, sColumn, counter, nTotal, sNr, q, amt: integer;

begin
  max := 10;
  sColumn := 0;
  nTotal := 1;
  SETLENGTH( arrayN, max );
  SETLENGTH( arrayS, 5, max );
  writeln('Input sales number from sales person.');
  readln(sNr);
  arrayN[sColumn] := sNr;
  arrayS[0, sColumn] := sNr;
  while (sNr <> 0) do
  begin
    if nTotal = LENGTH( arrayN ) then
    begin
      SETLENGTH( arrayN, LENGTH( arrayN ) + 5 );
    end;
    writeln('Give sales quarter ( 1 2 3 or 4 ) .');
    readln(q);
    writeln('Give amount of sale.');
    readln(amt);
    arrayS[q, sColumn] := arrayS[q, sColumn] + amt;
    writeln('Input sales number from sales person. Input 0 to quit.');
    readln(sNr);
    if ( sNr < LOW( arrayN ) ) or ( sNr > HIGH( arrayN ) ) then
    begin
      sColumn := nTotal;
      nTotal := nTotal + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      for counter := 0 to HIGH( arrayN ) do
      begin
        if sNr = arrayN[counter] then
        begin
          sColumn := counter;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    arrayN[sColumn] := sNr;
    arrayS[0, sColumn] := sNr;
  end;
  for row := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    for column := 0 to nTotal - 1 do
    begin
      write(arrayS[row, column] :5);
    end;
    writeln;
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln('Press < ENTER > to stop the program.');
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: It would help if you included both expected output and actual output. It's also time for you to learn how to debug.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick reply. I updated my post to include info on the expected vs actual output.

Comment: I can see neither expected or actual output. All I see is description.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. Would a screenshot of the end actual result be enough?

Comment: Not a screen shot. Your output is text. So include text.

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect thanks. Now, what do you know about debugging?

Comment: I know debugging includes finding and fixing errors in codes, but other than that I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: You need to learn how to do it. Find a tutorial on debugging.

Comment: The first problem that jumps out at me is. LOW( arrayN ) returns the lowest array index. I think you think it returns the lowest value stored in the array. Also HIGH( arrayN ) returns the highest array index. So this test will always be true "if ( sNr < LOW( arrayN ) ) or ( sNr > HIGH( arrayN ) ) then" because the lowest sNr is 100 and HIGH( arrayN ) only goes up to 10.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. Any ideas on what I could write instead of "if ( sNr < LOW( arrayN ) ) or ( sNr > HIGH( arrayN ) ) then" to show that I want sNr to not equal anything already in the range of arrayN for the statement to be true?

Comment: Problem found and resolved, thanks to you guys and the answer below. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: That's good, but please let me repeat my encouragement for you to learn debugging skills. If you had them you inspect the program at runtime and learn where it deviated from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get more sales person columns than you enter distinct sales person numbers is in the conditional check and the immediately following `begin - end` block

```
if ( sNr < LOW( arrayN ) ) or ( sNr > HIGH( arrayN ) ) then
begin
  sColumn := nTotal;
  nTotal := nTotal + 1;
end
```

Because your sales person numbers are not related to the index of ArrayN and you use 100, 200 and 300, the condition is always true. You can actually skip the above block (see below).

What you should do after entry of `sNr` is to check whether that number is already in 'ArrayN'. You actually do that in the `else` part of above mentioned conditional check:

```
else
begin
  for counter := 0 to HIGH( arrayN ) do
  begin
    if sNr = arrayN[counter] then
    begin
      sColumn := counter;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Remove the `else` and the outer `begin - end` block, leaving just the `for` loop.
You need to modify this check so that `nTotal` is increased after the loop if `sNr` is *not* found. It is easyer to increase `nTotal` just before the loop and decrease it if a match is found, e.g. within the same `begin - end` block where you assign `sColumn`.